# How can I send a data array back and forth between java and python?

Tags: java, python, arrays, jython

I have a java program and I need it to get some data calculated by a python script.

I've already got java to send an integer to python via jython's PythonInterpreter and displayed it, but I can't recover it to make other operations. Also, it would be great to send a full integer array rather than a single integer but I can't wrap my mind arround PyObjects and how to use them.

Is there any useful tutorial that covers arrays? I've been searching for a while but I just find integer and float related tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple solution then I suggest that you write and read the integers to a file. Perhaps not the most elegant way but it would only take a couple of minutes to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on similar project. Here's brief outline of what Java and Python was doing respectively.

**Java**
We used Java as a main server for receiving requests from clients and sending back responses after some data manipulation.

**Python**
Python was in charge of data manipulation or calculation. Data was sent from Java via socket network. We first defined the data we needed in *string* format, then cncerted them into *bytes* in order to have them semt via socket network.

Since there were limitations, though, using socket network, I changed it to Rest Api using Python Flask. In that way we could easily communicate with, not only but in this case mainly, Java with key-value json format. In this way, I was able to recieve any data type that could be passed through Api including array object you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution of writing/reading the numbers to a file somehow is not sufficient, you can try the following:
Instead of using Jython, you can use Pyro4 (and the Pyrolite client library for your java code) to call a running Python program from your java code.
This allows you to run your python code in a 'normal' python 3.6 interpreter for instance, rather than being limited to what version Jython is stuck on.
You'll have to launch the Python interpreter in a separate process though (but this could very well even be on a different machine)